# PHP Settings to ignore the WordPress error

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to run wordpress site under sartajphp framework. When i run wordpress site normally it worked fine. It may be ignore erros. But when i tried run under sartajphp it gives following php error.

```
SartajPHP Fatel Error:- Type:-8192 Msg:-Implicit conversion from float 4294967295 to int loses precision File:-D:\www\demo\apps\wordpress\wp-includes\pomo\mo.php on line no. 208
```

**Below is wordpress file error code:-**

```
$magic_big = ( (int) - 569244523 ) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

If i write a small value in this line then it worked fine. Is there any INI settings to ignore this error?
It is wordpress file so i don't want to modify it. So is there any good solution for this problem.

This code is working:- $magic_big = ( (int) - 569244523 ) & 0xFFFFFF;

Answer (score 1):

Errors should normally be good for telling you something went wrong

But if you really want, due to some special purposes, to hide Php errors in WP, then

Open Your wp-config. php File.

Replace the Debug Lines. Replace the existing lines with the following code snippet:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off'); 
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ); 
define('WP_DEBUG', false); 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Save and Upload.

Alternatively, if you can access the php.ini file, then use the following line (restart your httpd after changing the ini file):

```
display_errors = On
```

Comment: Thanks that is working but i amazed< How wordpress go to debug mode automatically when SartajPHP wrap wordpress in debug mode. That mean Wordpress detect that SartajPHP is in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix WordPress bug but you set ini to ignore error, second way is disable debug mode of SartajPHP